# How to understand the constant product formula?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, pancakeswap, swaps

Let's use this [transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xdd38b435d9840062db9106e23712873fa2da44c366fa737b17f7fc6d111ef076#eventlog) as an example.

Here 1 BUSD was transferred to [Zombie / BUSD LP](https://bscscan.com/address/0xde7c6452072a4bd77a6633969bdf579f8644f111) in exchange for `172054109197` Zombie tokens. (`3511308350` (2%) Zombie tokens were burned as part of the transaction.)

Here is the Swap event:

```
amount0In: 0
amount1In: 1000000000000000000
amount0Out: 175565417547
amount1Out: 0
```

Prior to the Swap, the reserve values were:

```
reserve0: 1203765031
reserve1: 6402195517789394391
```

after Swap, reserve values were updated to:

```
reserve0: 173257874228
reserve1: 44614233592769925
```

Everywhere that I've read, it is stated that *constant product formula* (`x*y=k`) requires that the `k` remains constant. However, this isn't the case here.

```
1203765031*6402195517789394391=7,706,739,085,939,811,390,553,341,121
173257874228*44614233592769925=7,729,767,272,594,744,235,790,992,900
```

Am I misunderstanding the function of the formula or is something else going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product *k* would actually be constant, if the swap fee was 0%. Since AMMs usually have a fee, the product of the reserves is not really a constant in practice.

> The name ‘constant product market’ comes from the fact that, when the
> fee is zero (i.e., γ = 1), any trade ∆β to ∆α must change the reserves
> in such a way that the product RαRβ remains equal to the constant k.

Source: [An analysis of Uniswap markets](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eguillean/papers/uniswap_analysis.pdf)

Comment: That makes sense. in this case, the difference is 0.2%, which aligns with what the PancakeSwap fees are.